Python exception stack trace not full when function is wrapped
I have two files t.py:
import functools
import traceback


def wrapper(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exception(e)

    return wrapped


@wrapper
def problematic_function():
    raise ValueError("Something went wrong")

and t2.py:
from t import problematic_function

problematic_function()

when I call from command line python t2.py, the stack trace information that has info from t2.py is lost when printing traceback.print_exception(e) in the t.py. What I get is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c/t.py", line 9, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/c/t.py", line 18, in problematic_function
    raise ValueError("Something went wrong")
ValueError: Something went wrong

where as if I remove the decorator I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/c/t2.py", line 3, in <module>
    problematic_function()
  File "/home/cu/t.py", line 17, in problematic_function
    raise ValueError("Something went wrong")
ValueError: Something went wrong

How do I get the full stack trace in the wrapped function as without the wrapper? Thanks!

Your code changes where the exception is caught (or not caught), and so changes the stack trace. The stack trace for an exception is from where the exception was raised, through to where it was caught. This feels a bit like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

To print the full stack trace you can unpack traceback.walk_tb to obtain the last frame of the stack from the traceback, and pass it to traceback.print_stack as a starting frame to output the entire stack:
def wrapper(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            *_, (last_frame, _) = traceback.walk_tb(e.__traceback__)
            traceback.print_stack(last_frame)

    return wrapped

Demo here

Since you grab the stacktrace and print it before the execution bubles back to a frame running in t2.py, the program is just doing exactly what you asked it to do: those frames are not in the stacktrace.
The call stack, the frames entered to get to the point of the exception are kept separated - as a chain of links in the Frame objects. That information is used to "bubble" the exception up, as it goes uncatched, but it is only added to the traceback as each outer level is reached. Since you catch the exception in t, that is what you have.
You´d have to introspect into the frames "manually" to get any caller information - you can get the Frames as attributes inside the traceback - or, you can just check the sys._getframe() call inside the wrapper itself, and track the outer Frames by following the .f_back attribute.
Of course any information you want to collect or format for printing on those frames are on your own code.
def wrapper(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            # inner trace:
            traceback.print_exception(e)
            # outer trace:
            f = sys._getframe()
            while f:
                 print(f"{f.f_globals.get("__file__", <"unknown">} at line {f.f_lineno}")
                 f = f.f_back
                 # you could use `inspect.getsource` to print lines of code 
          

    return wrapped

